# Css in middle of a text makes "\n" not work

Tags: c++, css, qt

I'm making a GUI app on Qt 4.8. I have a label where I show a text in white (I have already setted the stylesheet for it) and I want to change the color of the word UPDATE to red.

Initial code:

```
//all text in white
QString text(QString::fromUtf8("  Are you sure you want to UPDATE this?\n Something will happen."));
myLabel->setText(text);
```

To change the color of that word I know that it can be made with css like this:

```
//all text in white except UPDATE that will be in red 
QString text(QString::fromUtf8("  Are you sure you want to<font color=\"#f00\">UPDATE</font> this?\n Something will happen."));
myLabel->setText(text);
```

And YES, it works... BUT there is a problem: If you see after the word "this?" there is a "\n" which divides the line in two parts. In the first case it works perfectly but when I put the css in the second case then its like the program ignores that '\n' and I need to do the separation there and in that label (I can't use two labels)

I've tried to sepparate it with:

```
QString text(QString::fromUtf8("Are you sure you want to"));
        text.append(QString::fromUtf8("<font color=\"#f00\">UPDATE</font>"));
        text.append(QString::fromUtf8("this?\n Something will happen."));
```

But I got the same result...

Any idea of what am I doing wrong, what am I missing or how can I solve this problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you expect extra whitespace like `\n` to have any effect in html?

Comment: @KubaOber srry for the late reply, i was out. Because it was a normal text, not html so the normal behaviour is with /n. What I didn't know, as Frank Osterfeld said is that adding html makes all the text change to html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding HTML tags makes the label’s [text format detection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#textFormat-prop) detect HTML/Rich Text and interpret and render your string accordingly. When rendering rich text, a newline has no effect, as usual in HTML.

You need to replace the `\n` by `<br/>` to enforce a new line.

Comment: Yes, that's it! What an 'easy' issue, I didn't know about format detection. Thank you so much